# Find element and add class (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, list, nested

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">LEVEL 1</a>
      <ul>
         <li>...</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">LEVEL 1</a>
      <ul>
         <li>...</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I have a nested list and I want to use jQuery to add class to the LI that containts `A>LEVEL 1` based on this condition: `if a nested UL exists AFTER UL LI A, do x else y`.

Thanks.

Comment: where and when do you want to add the class? in x? in y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simply add a class to the `<li>` elements that have an anchor followed by a `<ul>` do this:

```
$("ul li:has(a + ul)").addClass("someClass");
```

If you really need different classes on whether it's true then you'll need some code:

```
$("ul li").each(function() {
  var a = $(this).children("a");
  if (a.next("ul").length > 0) {
    $(this).addClass("first");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("second");
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah, I just figured it out: $(".accordion ul li:has(ul)").addClass("CLASSY") but yours still better, thanks!