# Add class only if exists another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, class

I have the following code on my website

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper_inner">
      <header class="scroll_top stick transparent">
  <div class="responsive-menu-pro-button">
    <span class="responsive-menu-pro-box">
      <span class="responsive-menu-pro-inner">
```

What I want is that if in the "header" exists the class "light", a class "light-buttom" is added to the "span" with the class "responsive-menu-pro-inner"... So the code will look like:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper_inner">
      <header class="scroll_top light stick transparent">
  <div class="responsive-menu-pro-button">
    <span class="responsive-menu-pro-box">
      <span class="responsive-menu-pro-inner light-buttom">
```

And if the class "light" is not in the code (because it's added on scroll) the class "light-buttom" is deleted, and the code will resulta as the first.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find element and add class (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565816/find-element-and-add-class-jquery)

Comment: what you haven't done is [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve that with a bit of plain javascript like this:

```
if(document.querySelector(".wrapper header").classList.contains("light")) {
    document.querySelector(".wrapper header.light .responsive-menu-pro-inner").classList.add("light-buttom");
}
```

You can read about `classList` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

Comment: kudos for avoiding jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the class exists on your header with classList.contains() and then use classList.add() to add your "light-button" class to your span.

```
if (yourHeader.classList.contains("light") {
  yourSpan.classList.add("light-button");
}
```

To remove the "light-button" class you can use classList.remove()

```
if (!yourHeader.classList.contains("light") {
  yourSpan.classList.remove("light-button");
}
```

Comment: kudos for avoiding jquery